# listening to mouse and keyboard events simultaneously

Tags: angular, events, event-handling, dom-events, listener

I'm trying to listen to a scroll and a keydown event like this:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent(event){
      console.log("scrolled",event)
  }


@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) handleKeydownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent){
      console.log("ctrl pressed", event)
  }
```

I would like to listen to ctrl and scroll **simultaneously** and then catch that so I can stop the user from zooming in. But I don't know how to do this because hostlistener only listens to a single event

I also tried this, but that didnt work, I was still able to zoom in

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onEvent(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log("looks like you just tried to zoom in")
  }
```

how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rxjs` `merge` operator for this job

[More about merge operator](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/merge)

```js
import { merge, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  // Define a Subject to hold scroll event
  onScorll$ = new Subject();
  // Define a Subject to hold keydown event
  onkeydown$ = new Subject();
  // Define var to hold both of events
  both$;

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent(event){
      // console.log("scrolled",event)
      this.onScorll$.next(event);
  }

  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event']) handleKeydownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent){
        // console.log("ctrl pressed", event)
      this.onkeydown$.next(event);

    }

  constructor() {
    // We set both$ to listen to our events simultaneously
    this.both$ = merge(this.onScorll$, this.onkeydown$)
    // We subscribe to it to make it actually work
    //
    this.both$.subscribe((event) => {
      // Each time event occur you will be notified here
      // So you can do something like this to prevent it
      if(this.zoomEnabled) {
         event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please comment why you did not accept this as the answer, thanks

Comment: I also suggest you to read more about rxjs since it a MAJOR concept that you probably want to know and master

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer and for your time but this is the error that I get when I try your solution now "[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>"
Any ideas?